# How to put contact form on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put my form on a slider in such a way that slider seems to be running in the background of form. If I am using position absolute, then I have to apply a lot of margin and top pixels because there is a navbar above the slider and position absolute applies with respect to the parent element(navbar).

How can I exactly target the position absolute w.r.t my form, not navbar (parent element)?
Or

If you guys think that there can be a better option to deal with this then do share ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Here is the [demo link](http://codepen.io/zeeshan55/pen/NAoLgG)

HTML code:

```
    <section id="main-slider" class="carousel">


    <!--start-->
    <div id="ninja-slider">
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <ul>
                <li  class="dummySlide">
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/002.jpg"></a>
                </li>




                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/003.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/004.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/005.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/zess.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navsWrapper">
                <div id="ninja-slider-prev"></div>
                <div id="ninja-slider-next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end-->



    </section><!--/#main-slider-->

            <form role="form">

<!--First Row-->
   <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputTopic" class="control-label">Title</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="title">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="one">Mr.</option>
                    <option value="two">Miss</option>
                    <option value="three">Mrs.</option>
                    <option value="four">Dr.</option>
                </select>      
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputTopic" class="control-label">Sur-Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="surname" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you create a (*not*) working example here or on jsfiddle please, where we can try to help you. It is hard to tell without seeing it. Especially without your css ...

Comment: @eisbehr
Here is the link
https://codepen.io/zeeshan55/pen/NAoLgG

Comment: Why not use TWBS's carousel? No need for an extra plugin while it is already there for your use. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: @LuukSkeur
Thanks for your suggestion!
But I am comfortable with slider.
My problem is that my form is not getting responsiveness with my slider. It's going outside the slider on small resolutions  whereas i want to see this behave responsively with my slider.
.
If you know how can i do it then do share idea even if you are comfortable with  TWBS's carousel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do have a working example which uses TWBS's carousel. I created a wrapper `.container` which has a slider and a form as children. The slider is fullwidth while the form has a width of `70%` so it will always be responsive, the height is static for now, you could change this using media-queries. Here is my example:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 </div>
 <div class="myform">
   <h1> My Form </h1>
   <form>
      ...
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/tNAmbhKWb7

Comment: No, it's not the solution because my form has a lot of fields to display so on small screen it's coming outside the slider

Comment: Can you give me a favor? Visit my Codeopen link and see whether you can do the same by editing my code as you did in this demo?

Comment: That was not the question, then edit your question please. So, the slider height should adjust to the form height..? Make use of the plugin `match-height` and give the slider elements a background image with `background-size: cover`. My solution in a codepen: https://codepen.io/luukskeur/pen/GqzXLg

Comment: hey!
why form's fields get started to comes out on medium and  small screens?
Is it possible to make forms' height exactly equals to slider even on medium and small screens??

Comment: Like i said, @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide.. That was not your question, your question was to position the form on top of the slider. not to adjust the slider's height to the form's height. Please create a new question or have a look at this plugin http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: Hey there!
I was trying to work with your suggested plugin. It's difficult to use. Can you give em a favor by  helping me in applying this plugin in my code. ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have wrapper with `class="formSection"` for the form and also you should delete a `bottom: 0` from `formSection` class.

Comment: No ribba!
That's just helping to display my form inside one li (list item). As the slide moves on the form become disappear. But i want to keep my form fixed even if the slide moves on !

Comment: Moreover i am not using  class="formSection" in my code.

Comment: I tried your suggested code.
But, there is s a problem.
Actually i have a lot of fields in my form.
Just to give you an idea i just showed you two fields...........
Now!
My slider is responsive but the form moves outside the slider as slider moves to small resolutions. The form should be behave responsively with slider.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative; top:-200px; z-index:3; text-align:center;">
```

Where you declare the `<div class="row">`

put this code
  `<div class="row" style="position:relative; top:-200px; z-index:3; text-align:center;"`

This will definitely work